# How to Auto-Fill the fields in a shiny R form using a data frame info?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

I am programing a form in Shiny package in Rstudio. But I want to create an auto-fill form using info of my dataframes. I will give a little example.

Let's suppose that I had a data.frame with three columns. The first one contains the names of my students, the second contains his age and the third his last grade of the past test. I've create a form that has exactly three select input fields. The first one for select the names, the second an input number to select the age and the last for select his last grade. I want when I choose the name of the student in the first field, the other fields auto-complete the information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

The dataset I am using is as below. I had loaded the same data from a `csv` file.

```
autoFillDF <- structure(list(Name = c("ABC", "XYZ", "PQR"), Age = c(30L, 24L, 
27L), Grade = c("A", "B", "D")), .Names = c("Name", "Age", "Grade"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

ui.R code

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Auto Fill"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("p1", choices = autoFillDF$Name, selected = NULL, label = 'Name'),
      selectizeInput("p2", choices = NULL, label = 'Age'),
      selectizeInput("p3", choices = NULL, label = 'Grade')

    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('table')
    )
  )
)
```

server.R code

```
autoFillDF <- read.csv('..../test.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  updateApp <- reactive({
    data <- autoFillDF
    data <- data[data$Name %in% input$p1,]
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'p2', choices = data$Age, selected = data$Age, server = TRUE)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'p3', choices = data$Grade, selected = data$Grade, server = TRUE)

    data
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(updateApp()) 
  )

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. Really solves the problem.

Comment: @ElvinMitchellToro, If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) using the check mark under the voting arrows.